# Angular JS - Conditional Statement for Using JSON Object in HTML Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a JSON object in the following format:

```
{
   filters: [
        {Name: "pork",
         Active: true},
        {Name: "beef",
         Active: true},
        {Name: "chicken",
         Active: false}
   ]
}
```

I am constructing a SELECT list with the following:

```
ng-options="item.Name for item in filters"
```

I want to only construct an option if the "Active" key is `true`.  Is there a way for me to do this in the psuedo-JavasScript inside of the Angular directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-options="item.Name for item in filters | filter:{ Active : true }"`.